# how to create new Arraylist from other type

Tags: java, arraylist

I have 2 classes Employee and Manager that extends employee.
i have Arraylist type Employee that contains both employees and managers.
i want   generic method that will create a new ArrayList type Manager that will copy all the managers from the 1st List.

Answer (score 5):

The steps are:

- Create a new `List<Manager>`
- Loop through the `List<Employee>`
- For each element check if that element is a `Manager` using operator `**instanceof**`
- *If it is a Manager* add it to the `List<Manager>`
- Return the `List<Manager>`

It should be easy translate this steps in real code.

Answer (score 1):

Using java 8, you can use the stream methods to do the the steps [Davide Lorenzo MARINO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1803853/davide-lorenzo-marino) said in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35009186/1542723).

> - Create a new List
> - Loop through the List
> - For each element check if that element is a Manager using operator **instanceof**
> - If it is a Manager add it to the List
> - Return the List

Using java 8:

```
list.stream().filter(Manager.class::isInstance).map(Manager.class::cast).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

We first stream the items in the original list, filter the out the `Manager`s, cast the `Manager`s to `Manager` instances, then collect our result in a list.